# Dice Throwing Issue

Tags: c++

The rules of the game goes like that: Write  a program, that allow a certain number of players to do a certain number of dice throws. Let the program to calculate the sum of every player's throws and prints out the winner (the one with the biggest sum). If two or more players have the same sum, winner is the one, who threw more of 6's.

Here is what I got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

srand(time(NULL));
int numberOfPlayers;
int numberOfThrows;
int sum = 0;
int throws = 0;

cout << "Enter the amount of players: "; cin >> numberOfPlayers;
cout << "How many throws does each one have?? "; cin >> numberOfThrows;
cout << endl;

for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfPlayers; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < numberOfThrows; j++){
      throws = rand()%6+1;
      sum = sum + throws;
    }
    cout << "Sum of the player " << i << " is: " << sum;
    cout << endl;
    sum = 0;
}


  return 0;



}
```

I stuck at the point, where I need to print out the numbers that one threw, sum the throws of each player and scan for the one who threw more of 6's.

Comment: Look into `std::vector` for storing all the dice throws. Then you can count the 6's in that vector, and calculate the sum of all the elements in the vector.

Comment: you can print the value of `throws` after line `throws = rand()%6+1;` to show what number player threw. And also you can use a counter to keep track of 6s for each player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation using `std::vector` and the library `count` and `accumulate` algorithms.

Basically what happens here, is that I make a vector of vectors called playerThrows that contain a vector of throws for each player. This way you can keep track of every throw of each player. Then, when you loop through `numberOfPlayers`, I emplace a new vector in `playerThrows`, and for every throw, I push back a value to that vector of throws.

Then, after all throws have been made. I find the sum of all throws by calling the `accumulte` algorithm. And count the number of 6's using the `count` algorithm. What you want to do after, is up to you. For this example, I simply printed the values.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // You should look into the <random> header rather than srand
    srand(time(NULL));
    int numberOfPlayers;
    int numberOfThrows;

    vector<vector<int>> playerThrows;

    cout << "Enter the amount of players: "; cin >> numberOfPlayers;
    cout << "How many throws does each one have?? "; cin >> numberOfThrows;
    cout << endl;

    // Do throws for each player
    for (int i = 0; i != numberOfPlayers; ++i) {
        playerThrows.emplace_back(vector<int>{}); // Make vector for player

        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfThrows; ++j)
            playerThrows[i].push_back(rand() % 6 + 1);

        // Find sum
        auto sum = accumulate(playerThrows[i].begin(), playerThrows[i].end(), 0);

        // Find 6's
        auto sixes = count(playerThrows[i].begin(), playerThrows[i].end(), 6);

        cout << "Sum of player " << i + 1 << " is: " << sum << '\n';
        cout << "They had " << sixes << " 6's" << "\n\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You might also want to consider looking into the `<random>` header for better random number generation, and `<chrono>` for timing.

As requested in comments. Here is a version using only C++ headers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

int main() {

    // Using <random> header
    std::random_device seeder {};
    std::mt19937 generator(seeder());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> diceGenerator(1, 6); 

    int numberOfPlayers;
    int numberOfThrows;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> playerThrows;

    std::cout << "Enter the amount of players: ";
    std::cin >> numberOfPlayers;

    std::cout << "How many throws does each one have: ";
    std::cin >> numberOfThrows;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Do throws for each player
    for (int i = 0; i != numberOfPlayers; ++i) {
        playerThrows.emplace_back(std::vector<int>{}); // Make vector for player

        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfThrows; ++j)
            playerThrows[i].push_back(diceGenerator(generator));

        // Find sum
        auto sum = std::accumulate(playerThrows[i].begin(), playerThrows[i].end(), 0);

        // Find 6's
        auto sixes = std::count(playerThrows[i].begin(), playerThrows[i].end(), 6);

        std::cout << "Sum of player " << i + 1 << " is: " << sum << '\n';
        std::cout << "They had " << sixes << " 6's" << "\n\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know, but they were used in the original example, and so I kept them in there to not completely rewrite his code, but simply add what he was missing. As I stated, I would have used `<random>` and `<chrono>` instead of the C headers.

Comment: Updated with a version not using namespace + only C++ headers.

Comment: Thank you. It's better if beginners see as much idomatic C++ as possible, since many courses teach C with classes.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fulfill your needs is to create a structure for a player, which can store, the sum of his throws and also the number of 6's.

```
struct Player {
    int sum;
    int numSix;
    Player():sum(0),numSix(0){}
};
```

With this struct you can create an array with size of `numberOfPlayers`.

```
auto players = new Player[numberOfPlayers];
```

In your throwing loop add the throw to the player:

```
  throws = rand()%6+1;
  players[i].sum += throws;
  players[i].numSix += throws/6; //either 0 or 1 in case of 6
```

Finally you can loop through the players array and check who wins the game and also how many 6's each player had in case of equality.

Comment: There is no need for manual dynamic allocation here, and using C-arrays is unsafe and unnecessary when you can use the library containers. In this example you would also have to remember to `delete[]` the players afterwards. And in your struct, you should probably use in-class initializers on `sum` and `numSix` to have them default constructed to 0.

Comment: Good point, added the default constructor. 
Of course, use of std::vector is easier. But depending on the default capacity and number players and throws using std::vector results in several reallocations of memory and you don't get the maximum performance possible.